# Pass a variable from Server to UI

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Please have a look at the snippet at the end of the email.
I would like the second picker input to have a list of choices which is not the hard coded seq(100), but seq(nn), where nn is generated in the server part.
How can I pass this value from the server to the user interface (UI)?

Many thanks

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
          pickerInput("init_seed","Select the value of the random number seed",
                  choices=(c(1000,2000,3000)),
                  selected=c(1000),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                 `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F),
          pickerInput("2nd_choice","Select the value of the output random number",
                  choices=seq(100),
                  selected=c(10),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                 `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F)

)


server <- function(input, output) {
    nn <- reactive({
        set.seed(input$init.seed)
        round(runif(1,0,1000),0)
 })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

```html
<div style="width: 100% ; height: 400px ; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;" class="muted well">Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents</div>
```

Comment: Use `updatePickerInput` inside an `observe` or `observeEvent` (depending on your needs) to set the `choices` of the `pickerInput`.  Don't forget to add `session` as the third argument to your `server` function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please give me some code by editing my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP in comments.

Note that I've corrected the typo in the `nn` `reactive`.

If the only use of `nn` is to generate the upper limit of the selection list, the `reactive` can be deleted and the limit generated within the `observeEvent`.  I'm not sure that hard coding the random number seed inside the `reactive` (or the `observeEvent`) is a good idea.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("init_seed","Select the value of the random number seed",
              choices=(c(1000,2000,3000)),
              selected=c(1000),
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                             `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F),
  pickerInput("2nd_choice","Select the value of the output random number",
              choices=seq(100),
              selected=c(10),
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                             `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F)
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nn <- reactive({
    set.seed(input$init_seed)
    round(runif(1,0,1000),0)
  })
  
  observeEvent(nn(), {
    updatePickerInput(session, "2nd_choice", choices=seq(1:nn()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```